# Proving that we can apply the half-circuit model for the common-source differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, nmos, small-signal

This is the circuit I'm trying to solve through the half-circuit model:

[image]

To do so I need to first prove that \$V_{p}\$ is a small-signal ground under opposite symmetric excitation (\$v_{in1}=-v_{in2}\$), i.e. that in this small-signal circuit \$v_{p}=0\$ :
[image]

Given (\$v_{in1}=-v_{in2}\$) if neglect (OC) \$r_{1}\$ then it becomes trivial by equating the currents from the two current sources that \$v_{p}=0\$ however, by including \$r_{1}\$ I can't seem to get around it unless I also assume that \$v_{o1}=-v_{o2}\$ and this makes feel that I'm getting some circular logic involved because if \$v_{p}=0\$ then it also implies \$v_{o1}=-v_{o2}\$, so have I missed anything?

To summarize this in a question:
Can we by just using the fact that (\$v_{in1}=-v_{in2}\$) show that the circuit has \$v_{p}=0\$?

Comment: By inspection and ignoring DC offsets, Vp is ground. No need to prove it when the input voltages are differential and balanced and, the circuit is symmetrical.

Comment: This is a **linearized model** of the circuit and also balanced and symmetrical. So applying \$v_{in1}=-v_{in2}\$ implies that \$v_{o1}=-v_{o2}\$ as the transfer function is linear, if input= \$A\$ results in output = \$B\$ then \$-A\$ gives \$-B\$. This is valid because the behavior is **linearized** and both sides are identical.

Comment: @Andyaka I was hoping to prove it once (through equations), so I can proceed to conclude it by inspection afterwards.

Comment: Well, to any EE, it's pretty obvious but, if you want to prove it then that's up to you.

Comment: As an aside… this "half-circuit model" is some particular linear analysis technique/theorem? in 20 years I've never heard of it (or simple we don't give it that name here:D); or is it simply 'breaking up' the longtail in two 'ignoring' the emitter source?

Comment: Umm. it's just that whenever we prove the obvious fact that \$v_{p}=0\$ we can proceed to learn about what happens in the whole circuit by just solving one of its symmetric halves.